# Delphi TObjectStack<T> How to access Items other than top?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

In Delphi XE2, I need a generic object stack in which my calling code can access not just the top (via Peek), but Top-1, Top-2 etc. More of an "ObjectStackList" perhaps.

I haven't spotted a simple way to achieve that using the existing System.Generics.Collections classes. And TObjectStack's FItems is private in TStack, so no straightforward way to create a TObjectStack descendant which can access it.

I realize I could use ToArray to access items by index, but that creates a separate array which seems a waste of time and space just to access a single item in FItems.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you cannot get to FItems, you can use a helper to crack the class.

Comment: So far as I can tell, helpers aren't available for generic classes. Am I wrong?

Comment: How risky is the interceptor strategy? It relies on TStackInterceptor having the same memory layout as TStack, which at first I thought was a trick depending on the sequence of declarations FCount and FItems matching those in TStack. I've seen discussions critical of this approach on that basis.  However, I also see Delphi docs saying "You can increase the visibility of a member in a descendent class by redeclaring it", which seems what's going on here. The cast relies on matching memory layout, but wouldn't that still match even if the declaration of TStack changed?

Comment: I deleted my comment about interceptors since there was an error. If you declare `__TStackInterceptor<T> = class(TEnumerable<T>)
    private
      FCount: Integer;
      FItems: array of T;
  end;
` , this will replicate the memory footprint of `TStack<T>`. Access private FItems like this: `function TMyObjectStack<T>.Peek(itemIx: Integer): T;
begin
  Result := __TStackInterceptor<T>(Self).FItems[itemIx];
end;
` . The risk is that the declaration of `TStack` is changed at some point in later versions.

Comment: @LU RD... thanks for correcting. I wondered if that was what you intended. Now you are deliberately replicating TStack<T>'s memory layout, with risk of future changed layout. Instead, can't we make something from this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Classes_and_Objects "You can increase the visibility of a member in a descendent class by redeclaring it,"? Perhaps that doesn't work on private members?

Comment: I can't confirm that you can increase the visibility of a private variable. It would certainly be a good question, though. RTTI works, but there is a performance penalty. I used [`Hack #5: Access to private fields`](http://hallvards.blogspot.se/2004/06/hack-5-access-to-private-fields.html) from Hallvards blog as a reference for my suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `TObjectList` instead. You can access all the elements you want, and you can modify it at whichever end you want to treat as the top of a stack.

Comment: Yeah, that's my fallback approach -- actually I created a descendant of TObjectList<T> and added some basic stack methods. But it feels like reinventing a wheel... or at least the hubcaps.

Comment: I think Rob's answer best fits what you are asking for. Once you can do random access it's not a stack any more, it's just an array.

Comment: @David: There is a lot of utility in being able to access items in a stack relative to the top of stack, without it being just an array -- as a CPU stack demonstrates. There may certainly be cases where one would want to prohibit such access, but supporting it satisfies important use cases.

Comment: The CPU stack is an array. It's a contiguous block of random access memory. Delphi's list classes are badly named arrays.

Comment: @David: I take it that you are pointing out that a CPU stack (ie: the CPU's stack-specific registers and operations) has more features than a computer science abstract data type stack. The utility of those additional features (eg: stack frame) in supporting fundamental software operations (primarily "call" and recursion) strongly suggests that a library class that provides stack functionality (perhaps starting with just CS-strict operations) should be capable of being extended to support similar extended features.